# Proof that $\text{argmax}_x (f_\text{new}(x)) < \text{argmax}_x (f_\text{old}(x)) \text{ if } c_\text{new}(x) > c_\text{old}(x)$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to prove the following: Suppose we have the following function $f(x) = y(x)  \cdot (m-c(x)) $ and we know that $y(x)$ and $c(x)$ are positive, concave, and increasing.

I want to prove that when I change $c(x)$ such that $c_\text{new}(x) > c_\text{old}(x)\; \forall x$, that $\text{argmax}_x (f_\text{new}(x)) < \text{argmax}_x (f_\text{old}(x))$

Intuitively, this makes sense to me: We multiply $y(x)$ (increasing function) with the negative of $c(x)$, where -- for lack of more formal words -- $c_\text{new}$ constitutes a larger  "penalty" than $c_\text{old}$.

How would you approach a problem such as this? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to prove that $\max_xf_{new}(x)>\max_xf_{old}(x)$ (i.e. the value of the maximum increases) as stated in the text, or do you want to prove that $\mathrm{argmax}_xf_{new}(x)>\mathrm{argmax}_xf_{old}(x)$ (i.e. the location where the maximum is attained is increasing) as in the title? I believe the first is easily provable and the second might have a counterexample.

Comment: Ah sorry! The second! I’m interested in the argmax; thank you!

Comment: What are the smoothness assumptions on $y$ and $c$ ? (Continuity, differentiability, etc.)

Comment: Both y and c are continuous and (at least twice) differentiable and both R -> R.

Comment: There must be something wrong. If $y,c$ are concave and increasing (and non-constant) with domain $\mathbb{R}$, they must be decreasing indefinitely when $x\to-\infty$, so they cannot be positive. Are you sure that $y,c$ do not have domain (say) $(a,\infty)$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$? Or do you mean "convex" instead of concave?

Comment: yes, there is indeed a lower bound on the domain of $y$ and $c$. such that y and c have domain $[a, \infty]$. the relevant maximum lies in this domain.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a counterexample on the domain $(0,1)$:

- Let $m=1$
- Let $y(x)=\sqrt x$
- Let $c_{old}(x)=\sqrt x$
- Let $c_{new}(x)=\frac{1+x}{2}$

Then $f_{old}(x)=\sqrt x(1-\sqrt x)=\sqrt x-x$ with maximum at $f'_{old}(x)=0$ which gives $\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}-1=0$, i.e. $x=\frac14$.

But $f_{new}(x)=\sqrt x\left(1-\frac{1+x}{2}\right)=\frac{1-x}{2}\sqrt x$ has maximum at $f'_{new}(x)=0$ which gives $\frac{1}{4\sqrt x}-\frac{3\sqrt x}{4}=0$, i.e. $x=\frac 13 > \frac 14$.

If instead, you wanted $\mathrm{argmax}_x(f_{new})>\mathrm{argmax}_x(f_{old})$, a counterexample would be given by $c_{new}(x)=2\sqrt x$, which gives $f_{new}'(x)=0\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}-2=0\Rightarrow x=\frac{1}{16}$.

**EDIT:**

Of course, I should show that $c_{new}\geq c_{old}$, but this is equivalent to $1+x\geq2\sqrt x$, which is equivalent to $(1-\sqrt x)^2\geq0$, which is clearly true.

**EDIT 2:** (copied from comments)

When you want $c_{new}(0)=c_{old}(0)$ you can take the slightly modified $$c_{new}(x)=\frac{101}{200}(x^{0.01}+x)$$ instead, and all others ($m,y,c_{old}$) the same. You can numerically check that this solution works as well.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you; let's say we restrict $c_{new}(x)$ and $c_{old}(x)$ to be **linear** functions, then this counterexample doesnt work right? Would this assumption make the initial statement provable? Thank you!

Comment: On second thought, I think what differs from the setting that I have in mind (which I am trying to proof) is that in your example $c_\text{old}(a) < c_\text{new}(a)$ , where $a$ is the lower bound of the domain. In the setting I have in mind, $c_\text{old}(a) = c_\text{new}(a)$. maybe this is the critical assumption

Comment: The assumption $c_{old}(a)=c_{new}(a)$ alone does not change the result: Just take my $c_{new}$, but make the first part very steep until it becomes my function $c_{new}$ well before $\frac13$. I believe/hope this won't change the outcome too much.

Comment: I am not so sure. If instead of your $c_\text{new}$ I assume $c_\text{new} = x^{0.1}$, which lies above your $c_\text{new}$ in $[0,1]$, then your example doesn't hold. 
Essentially I think the two different y-intercepts at $a$, do significantly change the result... but i dont have a formal argument (yet).

Comment: I mean more like, if you take $c_{new}(x)=\begin{cases}2\sqrt x&x<7-4\sqrt3-\varepsilon\\\frac{1+x}{2}&x>7-4\sqrt3+\varepsilon\\\text{something smooth}&7-4\sqrt3-\varepsilon\leq x\leq 7-4\sqrt3+\varepsilon\end{cases}$, then there are seemingly two local maxima at $\frac1{16}$ and $\frac13$, but the latter is larger, so that is the global maximum, hence $\mathrm{argmax}_x f_{new}=\frac13$

Comment: I see your point. Thanks. But this piecewise $c_\text{new}(x)$ is not continously differentiable - which we need for the case we have in mind - correct? Do you maybe have another (non-piecewise) continuous differentiable function in mind?

Comment: You could take $c_{new}=x^{1/100}\frac{1+x}{2}$ in which case $f_{new}$ has maximum at $x\approx 0.3318$. I'll have a look at the linear case

Comment: Interesting function, however, this $c_\text{new}$ is not concave for the entire domain, as it becomes convex for $x>0.998$. While $c_\text{new} = x^{1/100} \frac{1+x+\epsilon}{2}$ becomes convex later depending on $\epsilon>0$, the function still turns to a convex function at "some" x, right? As i see it, this is a counter example in the closed domain, but not the semi open one?

Comment: whoopsie, I forgot to check concave (just assumed it was true). It does also not satisfy $c_{new}>c_{old}$ everywhere apparently, but you could take $c_{new}(x)=\frac{101}{200}(x+x^{1/100})$ instead, which satisfies all requirements.